# Self-supervised Target Definition in the Original Neural Language Model by Bengio et al (2003)

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings, language-models, self-supervised-learning

I understand how later neural language models (such as those used in the Word2Vec papers) framed the language modelling problem in a self-supervised way by learning to predict the *next* word (or any context word) in a sequence of words.

However, when reading Bengio et al's original Neural LM paper ([a neural probabilistic language model](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf)) it isn't very clear to me how they built the objective function for the optimizer.

From the paper:
[image]

Does this mean that the authors had to **build** the target by **manually** counting the empirical conditional probability for every "row" in the training set?

For instance, say the network is processing the string `"foo bar baz"` right now:

The *target* for this self-supervision instance would need to be **the number of times `"baz"` followed `"foo bar"` divided by all occurrences of `"foo bar"` in the validation set?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the same cross-entropy as with current language models; only the notation is different. It is well illustrated in Figure 1 of the paper:

[image]

Function $f$ already returns the $i$-th index of the final softmax. So, calling $f(w_t, w_{t-1}, \ldots, w_{t-n+1};\theta)$ actually means: take the embeddings of words $w_{t-1}, \ldots, w_{t-n+1}$ (denoted as function $C$), apply the non-linear layer and the softmax layer and take the predicted probability corresponding to $w_t$. The loss function can be therefore written as $\sum_t \log P (w_t|w_{t-1}, \ldots, w_{t-n+1})$, which is the log-likelihood. Today's convention is to use negative log-likelihood.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. So the target isn't a probability per se, but something like a one-hot-encoded vector where the correct word has a 1 and all other words have a 0 and the optimizer minimizes the residual accordingly, right?

Comment: Yes, the target is, in fact, a one-hot probability of the correct word.